# Android GStreamer fails to stream http url

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk, gstreamer

I am trying to build a music app on a android device with GStreamer ported on it. But when I try mp3 url streaming on http, it failed to handle stream (however, it works perfectly fine on Android devices with base Media Framework, OPENCore). So I wanted to know whether GStreamer supports http url streaming, or is there any other way of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes gstreamer can play http, you need to check if there are proper http source plugin install, by gst-inspect | grep http.

There is one souphttpsrc element that does that, check if its there.